# how to compile a git repo in yocto with jsoncpp libary?

Tags: git, makefile, yocto, recipe, jsoncpp

I wrote a recipe to compile a git repo in Yocto. The repository contains a Makefile to compile the code. The first time I was able to compile the code in Yocto, but when I added the jsoncpp library in my code, Yocto not able to compile it. It is showing some error like

```
test_1.cpp:5:10: fatal error: jsoncpp/json/json.h: No such file or directory
|     5 | #include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
|       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my recipe file. Please suggest me the change I need to done to compile the code.

**yocto_test.bb**

```
SUMMARY = "Hello World"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
DEPENDS = "jsoncpp"

SRCREV = "90052737ee51abca69a334a9208e2fec82d78c19"
SRC_URI = " \
    git://github.com/arghyaBiswas05/yocto-test.git \
    "

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake all
}

# Install binary to final directory /usr/bin
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}test_file ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Here is my **Makefile**

```
all:
    ${CXX} test_1.cpp -o test_file $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs jsoncpp)

install:
    cp test_file /usr/bin

clean:
    rm -rf test_file
```

Please suggest me the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile should have `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` used instead of the hardcoded `JSONLIB`. Those two variables are accordingly set by Yocto and are required to be able to find files provided by the recipes you have in `DEPENDS`.

If I can suggest, using meson, autotools or cmake might get you further quicker than writing Makefille by hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I change the Makefile as your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the command `pkg-config --cflags --libs jsoncpp`?  If you run it from Yocto what does it print?  You can ask your makefile itself to print this info, by adding something like this to the makefile:

```
$(info args: $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs jsoncpp))
```

Likely it will print something including the flag `-I/usr/include/jasoncpp`.  If it does then your `#include` is wrong, because a `-I` of `/usr/include/jasoncpp` plus an include of `jasoncpp/json/json.h` gives a full path of `/usr/include/jasoncpp/jasoncpp/json/json.h` and that file clearly doesn't exist.

I think most likely your include should be `#include <json/json.h>` but there's no way to know for sure without knowing how the `jsoncpp` package is installed, where it puts its headers, and what flags it expects.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer but note that Yocto is a cross compile system and running pkg-config on the build host shell will give different results than the pkg-confg that gets used during build

Comment: Yes, true: you need to run the `pkg-config` in the same environment where make is invoked.